# Por que o C# não permite heranças multiplas?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, herança

No C# podemos implementar diversas interfaces. Porém, porque não podemos herdar de mais de uma classe base?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Herdar de muitas classes concretas é uma grande fonte de problemas do ponto de vista do design de uma linguagem de programação: o que fazer se as duas superclasses tiverem um método do mesmo nome? E se tiver variáveis de instância do mesmo nome? Um problema particularmente complicado é a **herança diamante**. Considere o seguinte padrão de herança:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
 \ /
  D
```

A é uma superclasse que define um método virtual `foo()`. B e C são classes que herdam de A e reimplementam `foo`. Finalmente, D é uma classe que herda múltiplamente de B e C. Agora, se fizermos

```
A obj = new D();
obj.foo();
```

qual versão do método é chamada? A versão definida em B ou a definida em C?

Devido a essas complicações, muitas linguagens de programação (incluindo C# e Java) preferem deixar as coisas mais simples e permitem apenas a herança simples.

Dito isso, pode ser que a linguagem forneça alternativas para alguns dos usos mais comuns de herança múltipla. Por exemplo, C# permite que uma classe implemente mais de uma Interface, que é similar a herdar multiplamente de classes puramente abstratas.

Comment: Já vi programadores transformar o código em uma corrente, ao criar heranças sucessivas até a classe final (D herda C', que herda B, que herda A, que herda SuperA)...

Answer (score 7):

Basicamente, porque isso tornaria impossível a inter-operabilidade entre linguagens através do CLR (Common Language Runtime), pois diferentes linguagens definem a herança múltipla de formas sutilmente diferentes.

Em relacao ao problema do diamante, referido pelo @missingno, varias linguagens decidiram incluir heranca multipla, e existem varias solucoes para o problema do diamante. C++ obriga a uma resolucao explicita do metodo `foo` na classe `D`. Scala tem *traits*, e resolve o problema do diamante pela ordem de declaracao dos *traits*:

- `D extends B with C` -> a implementacao de `foo` em `C` vai ser usada.
- `D extends C with B` -> a implementacao de `foo` em `B` vai ser usada.

Mas, na realidade, a equipa de design de C# considera que em 99% dos casos, herança múltipla nao é verdadeiramente *necessária* (pessoalmente, eu concordo).
O principio *composition over inheritance* (composição em vez de herança) é talvez um dos principíos de design de software mais importantes, e que todos os engenheiros de software devem conhecer - vai-te salvar a vida muitas vezes ao longo da tua carreira.

Dito isto, existem projectos que tentaram criar o conceito de *traits* em C#, como por exemplo, o [NRoles](https://code.google.com/archive/p/nroles) atraves de um *post-compiler*, ou o [Heredar](https://web.archive.org/web/20160109133340/https://code.google.com/p/heredar/).

Fonte: [*Why doesn't C# support multiple inheritance?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-support-multiple-inheritance.aspx) / [Traits: How Scala Tames Multiple Inheritance](https://web.archive.org/web/20150403011440/https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/05/30/traits-how-scala-tames-multiple-inheritance/)

Comment: Como mais um exemplo, python resolve o problema de herança múltipla fazendo com que os métodos da classe base declarada primeiro prevaleça sobre o das posteriores (ex: class Classe(Base1, Base2):... serão herdados os métodos da Base1).
Um segundo ponto que considero relevante, um exemplo onde a herança múltipla poderia ser bem aplicada seria no Xamarin para trabalhar com protocols do iOS de forma próxima à nativa, já que os delegates são convertidos em classes abstratas, o que impede uma implementação múltipla. (Existem soluções implementadas: Strong Delegates e Weak Delegates).

Answer (score 5):

Como a pergunta já foi respondida, deixo aqui um exemplo para fins didáticos de como implementar a herança múltipla com interfaces em C#.

Vejamos o cenário.

```
public class Nadador
{
    public void Nadar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nadador nadando...");
    }
}

public class Corredor
{
    public void Correr()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Corredor correndo...");
    }
}

public class Ciclista
{
    public void Pedalar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ciclista pedalando...");
    }
}

public class Triatleta
{
    public void Correr()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Corredor correndo...");
    }

    public void Nadar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nadador nadando...");
    }

    public void Pedalar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ciclista pedalando...");
    }
}
```

E o programa de teste

```
class Program
{
    static void TorneioDeNatacao(Nadador atleta)
    {
        atleta.Nadar();
    }

    static void TorneioDeCiclismo(Ciclista atleta)
    {
        atleta.Pedalar();
    }

    static void TorneioDeAtletismo(Corredor atleta)
    {
        atleta.Correr();
    }

    static void TorneioDeTriatlon(Triatleta atleta)
    {
        atleta.Nadar();
        atleta.Pedalar();
        atleta.Correr();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Nadador nadador = new Nadador();
        Ciclista ciclista = new Ciclista();
        Corredor corredor = new Corredor();

        TorneioDeAtletismo(corredor);
        TorneioDeCiclismo(ciclista);
        TorneioDeNatacao(nadador);

        Triatleta triatleta = new Triatleta();

        TorneioDeTriatlon(triatleta);

        TorneioDeAtletismo(triatleta); //erro de compilação
        TorneioDeCiclismo(triatleta); //erro de compilação
        TorneioDeNatacao(triatleta); //erro de compilação
    }
```

Como o Triatleta sabe correr, pedalar e nadar, gostaríamos que ele pudesse competir também nas competições de atletismo, natação e ciclismo. Como permitir que isso seja possível? Usando interfaces, para simular a herança múltipla.

Vamos incluir também uma interface IAtleta que exibe as habilidades do atleta, para demonstrar o polimorfismo.

Segue o código:

```
public interface IAtleta
{
    void VerHabilidades();
}

public interface INadador : IAtleta
{
    void Nadar();
}

public interface ICorredor : IAtleta
{
    void Correr();
}

public interface ICiclista : IAtleta
{
    void Pedalar();
}

public class Atleta : IAtleta
{
    public virtual void VerHabilidades()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nenhuma");
    }
}

public class Nadador : Atleta, INadador
{
    public override void VerHabilidades()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sabe pedalar");
    }

    public void Nadar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nadador nadando...");
    }
}

public class Corredor : Atleta, ICorredor
{
    public override void VerHabilidades()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sabe correr");
    }

    public void Correr()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Corredor correndo...");
    }
}

public class Ciclista : Atleta, ICiclista
{
    public override void VerHabilidades()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sabe pedalar");
    }

    public void Pedalar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ciclista pedalando...");
    }
}

public class Triatleta : Atleta, ICorredor, INadador, ICiclista
{
    public override void VerHabilidades()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sabe correr, pedalar e nadar");
    }

    public void Correr()
    {
        new Corredor().Correr();
    }

    public void Nadar()
    {
        new Nadador().Nadar();
    }

    public void Pedalar()
    {
        new Ciclista().Pedalar();
    }
}
```

Agora podemos alterar o nosso programa de teste, para mostrar as habilidades de cada atleta.

```
class Program
{
    static void TorneioDeNatacao(INadador atleta)
    {
        atleta.Nadar();
        atleta.VerHabilidades(); // método polimórfico
    }

    static void TorneioDeCiclismo(ICiclista atleta)
    {
        atleta.Pedalar();
        atleta.VerHabilidades(); // método polimórfico
    }

    static void TorneioDeAtletismo(ICorredor atleta)
    {
        atleta.Correr();
        atleta.VerHabilidades(); // método polimórfico
    }

    static void TorneioDeTriatlon(Triatleta atleta)
    {
        atleta.Nadar();
        atleta.Pedalar();
        atleta.Correr();
        atleta.VerHabilidades(); // método polimórfico
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Nadador nadador = new Nadador();
        Ciclista ciclista = new Ciclista();
        Corredor corredor = new Corredor();

        TorneioDeAtletismo(corredor);
        TorneioDeCiclismo(ciclista);
        TorneioDeNatacao(nadador);

        Triatleta triatleta = new Triatleta();

        TorneioDeAtletismo(triatleta);
        TorneioDeCiclismo(triatleta);
        TorneioDeNatacao(triatleta);
        TorneioDeTriatlon(triatleta);
    }
```

Agora percebemos que o triatleta consegue participar de todas competições. Mesmo estando numa competição que exige apenas uma habilidade, todas habilidades do triatleta são mostradas por polimorfismo no método VerHabilidades().

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta que foi colocada. Além disso, o próprio OP afirmou "No C# podemos implementar diversas Interfaces".

Comment: Sim, ajustei o topo do texto com o objetivo do meu post.

Comment: Para o caso de métodos, essa forma de implementar uma herança múltipla está ok. Agora, para o caso de propriedades da classe, existe uma forma?