# Qual a diferença entre System.Web.Http e System.Web.Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um projeto MVC e nele vou ter controles normais e controles fornecendo serviços via *webservices* (`Controller` e `ApiController`).

E não sei qual usar porque não sei qual é o melhor.

Comment: Ambos são ultrapassados, não os use.

Comment: Devo ou não extender Controller e ApiController?

Comment: Deve. È a única forma de consumi-la já que ela é abstrata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Qual a diferença entre `System.Web.Http` e `System.Web.Mvc`?

Aqui estamos falando de *namespaces*, e que servem a propósitos diferentes.

[A implementação de `System.Web.Mvc` está aqui](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/). [A implementação de `System.Web.Http` está aqui](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/).

`System.Web.Mvc` implementa, em grande parte, a arquitetura ASP.NET MVC, sendo o MVC5 a última versão deste padrão. Passa a ser descontinuada de novos lançamentos com o lançamento e estabilização do ASP.NET Core. Apenas *bugs* e algumas manutenções serão feitos, assim como no caso do Web Forms.

`System.Web.Http` implementa, em grande parte, a arquitetura ASP.NET Web API, sendo a versão 2.2 a última deste padrão, também passando a ser descontinuada com o lançamento do ASP.NET Core, que tem por um dos objetivos unificar as arquiteturas.

> Tenho um projeto MVC e nele vou ter controles normais e controles fornecendo serviços via *webservices* (`Controller` e `ApiController`).

Aqui temos alguns problemas. *Web Services* possuem seu próprio padrão de projeto (o ASP.NET Web Service, [roteiro aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70(v=vs.90).aspx)). O que você quer fazer, pelo que eu entendi, é servir algum tipo de dado como um *Web Service*, mas usando ou um *Controller* MVC ou um *Controller* Web API.

> E não sei qual usar porque não sei qual é o melhor.

Aqui vale a pena falar sobre as diferenças sobre o [`System.Web.Http.ApiController`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/ApiController.cs) e sobre o [`System.Web.Mvc.Controller`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs) (que, acredito eu, seja afinal o objetivo da pergunta).

Antes, é importante dizer que ambos podem servir qualquer tipo de dados. A diferença é que o `Controller` fará isso usando um `ActionResult` (ou seja, uma classe abstrata que possui várias derivações, dependendo do que se quer servir), enquanto que o `ApiController` usará um [`HttpResponseMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx).

A implementação de `Controller` sugere facilidades para trabalhar com HTML, JSON, requisições Ajax e tradicionais. Em resumo, os tradicionais sites de internet. Menos abrangente e mais especializado.

A implementação de `ApiController` sugere facilidades para trabalhar com verbos HTTP (navegadores tradicionais normalmente implementam só `GET` e `POST` com alguns artifícios para implementar os demais), objetos serializados e arquitetura sem estados, ou seja, o uso de sessão é desestimulado ([ainda que existam formas disso ser feito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594229/accessing-session-using-asp-net-web-api)). Em resumo, feito para trabalhar com aplicativos de celular, integração com outros sites, repositório de informações e arquivos. Mais abrangente e menos especializado.

### Conclusão

Considerando que a ideia é montar um serviço que funcione de forma semelhante a um *Web Service*, `ApiController` é uma opção mais adequada (tanto para a Web API 2.2 quanto para o ASP.NET Core). `Controller` também pode ser usado para produzir o mesmo resultado, mas exigirá um pouco mais de trabalho para compor e formatar o elemento serializado (como XML, JSON, YAML, BSON, etc.).

[Ainda sobre Web API, a parte de *Media Formatters*](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) pode ser bastante esclarecedora para sua implementação.

Answer (score 12):

Essa pergunta ficou datada, hoje nem dá pra questionar nada disso, quem incentivou a pessoa ficar na versão antiga induziu a pessoa a erro. Veja mais em [O .NET Framework está morto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

## Tem solução mais moderna

Se vai aprender agora, começar um projeto novo e não tem nada legado, aconselho usar o [ASP.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52158/101) que é mais moderno. Esqueça estas classes do `System.Web`, todo o modelo da tecnologia nova é mais adequada para o modelo web atual. A Microsoft aconselha fazer o mesmo e não evoluirá mais as versões antigas (ainda será suportado).

A versão legada é mais madura, claro, mas [tem muita gente usando o Core sem problemas, até mesmo em produção](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/06/27/announcing-net-core-1-0/). O resto é [FUD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medo,_incerteza_e_d%C3%BAvida). Avalie o que é melhor para você hoje e para o futuro.

Ainda que no momento desta resposta ele possa ter alguns pequenos problemas, estará 100% em breve, até porque [a versão 1.0 final já está lançada](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/announcing-asp-net-core-1-0/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). E faz tempo que a Microsoft parou de lançar as coisas repletas de problemas. [Acompanhe o *roadmap*](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) (o desenvolvimento da tecnologia levou 2 anos). Algumas pessoas tiveram problemas no passado. Mas estas coisas são transitórias. Fica aqui uma resposta que serve para daqui pra frente e não para o passado.

Nesta nova tecnologia não há distinção entre `Controller` e `ApiController` eliminando a confusão, só a primeira existe de forma mais flexível.

Ainda [pode ver a classe na tecnologia mais nova](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs) e confirmar como é algo mais bem pensado e que há ganhos em começar por ele sempre que possível. Não vou entrar em detalhes das vantagens do ASP.NET Core porque não é o foco da pergunta. A desvantagem para quem não tem legado é transitória, e até questionável no momento atual. Cuidado com informações defasadas, é melhor confiar no que não é transitório.

## Herança

Estas classes são abstratas, então a única forma de consumi-las é herdando delas. Ou você herda de uma ou de outra, dependendo de sua necessidade.

Lembrando que é possível criar *controllers* sem herdar destas classes, mas esta é a forma mais prática e comum.

Em casos mais complexos é possível herdar destas classes para uma outra classe abstrata sua que personaliza o controlador base para ser usado nos controladores concretos.

## Diferenças entre elas

Claro que há projetos que valem a pena ficar na tecnologia mais antiga. Neste caso segue o motivo principal para escolher uma outra classe.

Segundo uma [resposta no SOen com 193 votos positivos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9495189/221800) no momento que escrevo esta resposta, a `Controller` é usada quando pretende gerar *views* e a `ApiController` é usada quando só gerará uma resposta de dados serializados (JSON é o preferido) que não renderizará uma página.

**Ainda que possa usar para alguma outra coisa, a `ApiController` não foi feita para isto**, a não ser, é claro, que os dados seja HTML para uma parte de uma página. Isto é [reforçado pela página oficial da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Assim como pode, até o ASP.Net MVC 5 não era ideal enviar dados para requisições diversas através da `Controller`.

No ASP.Net antigo a `ApiController` é usada pelo [ASP.Net WebAPI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49090/101) para atender principalmente WebServices/[RESTful API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45783/101).

Exemplo usando o MVC terminando com a delegação para a visão concluir a ação:

```
public class MoviesController : Controller {
    private MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext(); //pegar do model
    // GET: /Movies/
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View(db.Movies.ToList()); //note a delegação para a view
    }
}
```

[É possível ver o código fonte da classe abstrata](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs).

Exemplo usando a WebAPI. Para fazer requisições aqui normalmente se usará AJAX ou alguma forma de requisição via HTTP em qualquer tipo de aplicação que deseje consumir seu *webservice*.

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController {
    Product[] products = new Product[] { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
    };
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts() {
        return products;
    }
    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id) {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ProductsController.cs).

Se estiver curioso de como é o código da classe abstrata, [é possível ver seu fonte](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/ApiController.cs).

Comment: O ASP.NET Core ainda não está estável. Tem vários problemas em diversas etapas do desenvolvimento. Ainda não é hora de recomendá-lo.

Comment: Mas é questão de dias, antes de alguém conseguir terminar um projeto importante começado agora ele já estará ok, até porque já está quase ok. A versão final deve ser lançada esta semana (ou algo assim) e mesmo que ela tenha pequenos problemas, já irão corrigir. Tem muita gente usando usando ele com sucesso. Não recomendar tornará a resposta ultrapassada. As respostas aqui precisam durar. Acho contraproducente recomendar algo antigo que se tornará legado a não ser em casos bem específicos que seriam determinados pela pergunta. Pelo menos logo poderá voltar e trocar o negativo de resposta.

Comment: @bigown Desculpe, mas não consigo concordar com você. Acho que minha resposta está segura por um período mínimo de 2 anos. O Asp.NET Core é uma excelente mudança, e estou mais ansioso do que você para que fique estável. Porém, não basta a Microsoft falar que algo está pronto. Só quem já passou por algum bug em **produção** que era causado por atualizações sabe do que estou falando. Seu sistema parar e você depender de algo para poder corrigir. Por isso acho que sua resposta está com o foco no lugar errado. O AP fez a pergunta hoje, ou seja, com as tecnologias atuais.

Comment: Porém, sua resposta da a entender que ele deve migrar para o Asp.NET Core, o que não é verdade. O que o fabricante fala sobre algo novo sempre é positivo, o que a comunidade que o usa fala, nem sempre.

Comment: @RandradeQuer dizer que a Microsoft está errada? As pessoas que estão usando com sucesso e até me produção estão erradas? Vai levar dois anos pro produto ficar estável? Na data de hoje o produto está tão cheio de bugs quanto estava há meses atrás? É melhor confiar em informação desatualizada? O fato de você confiar no produto e não poder usar não quer dizer que ele seja rui,. O fato dele não ser adequado para alguns, não quer dizer que não é para o AP.

Answer (score 10):

Não existe isso de **"Qual é o melhor para usar?"** Eles possuem finalidade diferente.

Se seu projeto for em Asp.NET MVC, não há necessidade de **ApiController**, da mesma forma que se for Web API, não há necessidade de ter **MVC Controller**.

Agora, se seu projeto usarem ambos, separe os dois. `C#` [não possui Herança múltipla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3602/20615), o que indica que seu **Controller** não "é para ser" os dois, tanto que suas finalidades são distintas.

Em resumo, Asp.Net MVC tem foco em retorno de `Views`, em outras palavras, páginas para o Usuário, enquanto Web APItem foco em retorno de serviços REST, na maioria de seus casos, retornando JSON.

No [Asp.NET Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/) isso mudou, e o mesmo controller pode retornar os dois. Porém, essa versão não está estável e está com alguns bugs, tanto que é utilizado somente por "entusiastas", e quem acompanha o [Channel 9 da Microsoft](https://channel9.msdn.com/) sabe disso.

Comment: Randrade, eu não entendi isso de "separe os dois"... Como eu separaria? Tipo eu vou ter uma área para usuários do site, e outra que disponibiliza dados para outras aplicações tudo num mesmo contexto, num mesmo servidor, utilizando autenticação por token...

Comment: @diegocolli Simples, Os controllers referentes ao Web API você herda de **ApiController**, os outros de **Controller**. Um mesmo controller não deve fazer os dois.