# Herança múltipla e problema do diamante

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, herança

O que é o problema do diamante?
Como as linguagens o tratam? E se tratam de forma diversa porque existe essa diferença?

Comment: O Java 7 trata o problema do diamante impedindo que exista herança múltipla. No Java 8, com métodos padrão para interface, esse problema passou a ocorrer, e foi tratado forçando dizer de onde se está pegando o valor, nada de implícito

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tem fonte disso do java-8? Parece interessante, gostaria de ler mais a respeito.

Comment: @Articuno https://stackoverflow.com/q/16764791/4438007 ; eu vi em um posto de blog também, acho que em documentação oficial, mas não achei rapidamente

Comment: @Articuno , resolução por explicidade: http://www.lambdafaq.org/how-are-conflicting-method-declarations-resolved/

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado fiz o teste, realmente obriga a implementar o método default e apontar pra qual método que usaremos mesmo.

Comment: Relacionadas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3602/91, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173198/91 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42970/91

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se uma classe herdar duas classes (implementações concretas), pode haver conflito de implementações.

**Exemplo:**

```
class ClasseBase1 
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClasseBase1");
    }
}

class ClasseBase2 
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClasseBase2");
    }
}

class ClasseDerivada : ClasseBase1, ClasseBase2
{
}
```

A classe `ClasseDerivada` herda duas implementações do método `Foo`, o que gera um conflito pois o compilador não sabe qual método usar.

No C# herança múltipla de classe é proibida, para evitar este problema *diamante*.

Agora herança múltipla de interfaces é permitida, pois interfaces não são implementações. O código a seguir é válido.

**Exemplo:**

```
interface IFoo1 
{
    public void Foo();
}

interface IFoo2
{
    public void Foo();
}

class ClasseDerivada : IFoo1, IFoo2
{
}
```