# Como utilizar interfaces como DbSet's no Entity Framework em C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, interface, entity-framework-core

Olá, estou fazendo uma solução onde toda minha camada de negócios está em um projeto separado e nesse projeto eu criei a estrutura relacional da camada a partir de interfaces como mostra o exemplo abaixo:

```cs
// interfaces de definição de características 
public interface IHasIndex {
    int Id { get; set; }
}
...
// estrutura da aplicação
public interface IEmpresa: IHasIndex {
    string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
}
public interface IUsuario: IHasIndex {
    string Login { get; set; }
    string Senha { get; set; }
    IEmpresa Empresa { get; set; }
}
...
```

A intenção é aproveitar da herança múltipla que as interfaces me permitem e padronizar a nomenclatura dos campos assim como também permitir o uso das interfaces de definição de características como seletores específicos, generalizando a aplicação, reduzindo código, padronizando métodos, etc...

Meu problema está na hora de gerar os modelos dessa solução. Estou trabalhando com Entity Framework Core e, mesmo que ele permita a utilização de interfaces na definição dos `DbSet<T>` (como mostra [nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061009/using-interfaces-with-dbset-possible-with-ef-core)) Eu pretendo usar classes de Modelo que implementam as interfaces da lógica da aplicação, como mostrado abaixo:

```cs
[Table("Empresa")]
public class EmpresaModel: IEmpresa {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
}
[Table("Usuario")]
public class UsuarioModel: IUsuario {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }

    public int EmpresaId { get; set; } // FK para Empresa
    [ForeignKey("EmpresaId")]
    public EmpresaModel Empresa { get; set; }

}
```

Ao definir que vou usar `EmpresaModel` como a `IEmpresa` na classe `UsuarioModel`, o C# me diz que a interface não foi implementada. Ao meu ver, se `EmpresaModel` implementa `IEmpresa`, então (teoricamente) eu poderia usar da classe invés da interface. Como resolver?

> **EDIT:** Para deixar a situação mais clara baseado no que o @MarconcilioSouza disse sobre herança múltipla, vou expandir a interface IEmpresa com todos mais atributos e heranças...

```cs
// interfaces de definição de características 
public interface IHasVisibility {
    bool Visivel { get; set; }
}
public interface IHasDefault {
    bool Padrao { get; set; }
}
public interface IHasCreationEvent {
    bool CriadoEm { get; set; }
}

// estrutura da aplicação
public interface IPessoaJuridica {
    string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
    string NomeFantasia { get; set; }
    string Cnpj { get; set; }
    string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }
    string InscricaoMunicipal { get; set; }
}
public interface IPessoaFisica {
    string Nome { get; set; }
    string Sobrenome { get; set; }
    string Cpf { get; set; }
    string Rg { get; set; }
}
public interface IEndereco : IHasIndex {
    string Logradouro { get; set; }
    string Numero { get; set; }
    string Complemento { get; set; }
    string Bairro { get; set; }
    string Localidade { get; set; }
    string Uf { get; set; }
    string Pais { get; set; }
    string Cep { get; set; }
}
public interface IContato: IHasIndex {
    string Tipo { get; set; }
    string Descricao { get; set; }
    string Observacao { get; set; }
}
public interface IContatoWithDefault: IContato {
}
public interface IEmpresa : IHasIndex, IHasDefault, IHasCreationEvent, IHasVisibility {
    IPessoaJuridica PessoaJuridica { get; set; }
    IPessoaFisica PessoaFisica { get; set; }
    IEndereco Endereco { get; set;}
    ICollection<IContatoWithDefault> Contatos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: recentemente tentei fazer algo semelhante, mas não dediquei muito tempo a isso. Minha solução foi passar o tipo da classe na declaração... `public interface Usuario<TEmpresa>` ... `public TEmpresa Empresa {get;set;}`; pra mim atendeu sem problemas, mas se alguém tiver uma solução melhor, atualizo meu código =]

Comment: Não me parece o melhor uso de interfaces e no caso como todas as entidades terão uma propriedade `int Id`, por que não criar simplesmente uma classe `BaseModel` com e que será herdada pelas outras?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis eu também pensei nisso, o problema é que com isso começa a virar gambiarra... imagina se eu tenho uma interface que tem muitas interfaces como propriedades, olha o tanto de tipo que deveria ser passado para resolver isso...

Comment: sim, como falei, no meu caso não foi problema. Aguardo se outro membro terá uma solução melhor / adequada. vlw

Comment: @LeandroAngelo o problema de herdar uma `BaseModel` é que eu não poderia me beneficiar de heranças múltiplas. Usando a abordagem acima, eu posso ter "N" propriedades específicas, ex: `IHasState` (controle de estado), `IHasVisibility` (ocultável), `IStartAndEnd` (obriga a ter datas de início e fim), etc...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo e ainda posso padronizar a nomenclatura de todos os campos conforme eu quiser. A vantagem disso é você ter uma estrutura muito mais lógica, simples e intuitiva

Comment: @RovannLinhalis eu até achei uma forma de fazer, (a que coloquei no projeto) mas a própria descrição no stack ta muito "pelos coco", daí to procurando uma mais inteligente e otimizada... se eu achar eu posto e vc pode usar ai =D

Comment: só uma observação... pra declarar as interfaces, utilizei .net standart, assim consegui utiliza-las no .net core implementando uma api, e no .net framework, implementando uma aplicação winforms.

Comment: Se você substituir a propriedade que usa sua EmpresaModel `public EmpresaModel Empresa { get; set; }` por uma propriedade com a interface IEmpresa `public IEmpresa Empresa { get; set; }` não atenderia?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis eu também estou usando isso, na minha solution tenho 3 projetos (até o momento) sendo Lib (.NET Standard), Api (.NET Core), Mobile (Xamarin) mas usando essa metodologia posso ter "n" que não vai fazer diferença e todos terão a mesma lógica

Comment: @Renan é exatamente nisso que estou tendo problema... O EFCore não consegue implementar estruturas não inicializáveis por esse motivo eu tenho que mexer na minha implementação entende?

Comment: isso esta mais para uso de classe abstrata  https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza se eu usar classes abstratas eu não vou poder aproveitar de heranças múltiplas... por esse motivo que não posso usar

Comment: você não vai poder herdar duas classes, mas faze o que você fez com as interfaces você pode

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza em C# a única forma de fazer herança múltipla é assim kra...

Comment: e em qual lugar do seu exemplo de código vc esta usando herança múltipla ? não vejo você usar `EmpresaModel: IEmpresa , IUsuario`  ou  `UsuarioModel: IUsuario ,IEmpresa  `. você só esta herdando uma interface que já herda de outra interface. veja isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3602/43340

Comment: O código é um exemplo e irei utilizar herança nesse projeto. Vou alterá-lo para que tenha herança para você entender melhor...