# Como é possível implementar a herança múltipla em linguagens de programação que não suportam nativamente esse recurso?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, swift, herança

Linguagens como C# e Swift suportam herança única, ou seja, um objeto ou classe pode herdar apenas de uma única classe mãe.

Quais técnicas poderiam ser utilizadas nessas linguagens, para utilizar o conceito de herança múltipla?

Comment: É interessante que leia [Por que todo mundo odeia herança múltipla em C++ e qual sua diferença para mixins?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42970/137387) e [Por que o C# não permite heranças multiplas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3596/137387)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível sem a linguagem fornecer isso. Dá para fazer o que você quiser de um jeito ou de outro, mas certamente não será herança múltipla como costuma ser definida.

Sobre Swift não posso falar por não ser usuário dela. Sei que os protocolos são semelhantes às interfaces do C#, pode ser que se aplique igual.

Em C# pode usar [interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para isso. Permite você ter o contrato do tipo e até a [implementação dos métodos, desde a versão 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). O que você não pode ter, são os campos, e isso determina que não está fazendo herança múltipla.

Também poderia usar uma interface com [métodos de extensão](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas quase sempre isso não é necessário mais.

De maneira geral a herança múltipla verdadeira é pouco útil e causa muitos problemas. Se você considerar que o mais importante pode fazer com interface e que campos deveriam ser detalhes de implementação de cada classe mesmo, melhor assim.